# Norwegian language in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I’m looking for a solution to display the Norwegian language in a Zend framework project (zf 1.12) while using `Zend_Locale`.

As far as a 5 digit language identifier is needed, I tried out using `no_NO` which seems not to exist, since the fallback language was used.

The following two written, Norwegian languages work fine:

- `nb_NO`: Bokmål
- `nn_NO`: Nynorsk

My only problem is that the displayed language for customers will be for example "Norwegian Bokmål"; I would expect only "Norwegian". As far as I’m not a native, I ask myself if this would be normal behaviour of a Norwegian page, to display the kind of written language, or not?

Is there a workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least I could find a workaround which worked for me. I override the translation array of the dialcet `$aLanguageTranslation["nb"]` in my code with the data provided for `$aLanguageTranslation["no"]` which seems to work fine.

This may not be the best solution, but one that works fine for me.